# How to create multiple database sequelize sessions in NodeJS

Tags: node.js, postgresql, aws-lambda, sequelize.js, serverless-framework

I am creating a backend APIs using Serverless framework in which I am using Nodejs with Sequelize. My dialact is postgresql. I need to interact with two databases at the same time and maintain session.

What I am doing is this
My folder structure is

- Repo
- - database 1
- - - model1.js
- - database 2
- - - model2.js

```
  const db = {};
  const DBs = DB_NAME.split(',');
  console.log(DB_NAME);
  console.log(DBs);
  for(let i = 0; i < DBs.length; ++i) {
    let database = DBs[i];
    //Store the database connection in our db object
    db[database] = new Sequelize(database, DB_USERNAME, DB_PASSWORD, {
      host: DB_HOSTNAME,
      port: DB_PORT,
      dialect: DB_DIALECT,
      pool: {
        max: 10,
        min: 1,
        idle: 20000,
        acquire: 20000,
      },
      define: {
        underscored: true,
        timestamps: true,
        paranoid: true,
      },
    });
}
```

this runs fine. but when I try to add models

```
fs
    .readdirSync(__dirname + '/product')
    .filter(file =>
        (file.indexOf('.') !== 0) &&
        (file !== basename) &&
        (file.slice(-3) === '.js'))
    .forEach(file => {
        const model = db.product.import(path.join(__dirname + '/product', file));
        db.[model.name] = model;
    });


// Add models from database2 folder

fs
    .readdirSync(__dirname + '/painted')
    .filter(file =>
        (file.indexOf('.') !== 0) &&
        (file !== basename) &&
        (file.slice(-3) === '.js'))
    .forEach(file => {
        const model = db.painted.import(path.join(__dirname + '/painted', file));
        db.[model.name] = model;
    });
```

This above gives error that import is not a function of undefined

Can anyone please help me in that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was making an error while adding the model into the db object.

Instead of

```
db.[model.name] = model;
```

I needed to do

```
db.painted.[model.name] = model;
```

and

```
db.product.[model.name] = model;
```

accordingly.

everything works fine. I can maintain two session on every API call